# How to get "nonbreaking vertical space"?

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, mdframed

Using `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` (my existing code base uses `mdframed`, I'm interested in moving to `tcolorbox`), I want to have three things:

- vertical space between the pretty box and the next paragraph, but
- no page break or column break in that vertical space, at least one line of text must be present (two would be better, but I'll settle for one for now), and
- I don't want to break the pretty box.

Starting with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside,extrafontsizes]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{printlen}

\newlength{\testskip}
\setlength{\testskip}{1\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newenvironment{test}{
\begin{mdframed}
}{
\end{mdframed}
}

\title{Suppressing Page Breaks MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\begin{test}
Testing 1 mdframed
\end{test}
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

Adding `\nopagebreak` gets me part way.

```
\newenvironment{test}{
\begin{mdframed}
}{
\end{mdframed}\nopagebreak
}
```

This pulls the paragraphs a bit closer together to make room for one line of text and copies the line of text from the next page. If I add `\vskip0.5\baselineskip` above `\lipsum[5]` there isn't enough space to reduce, and the `mdframed` gets pushed to the next page.

So far, so good... but I cannot find a way to add vertical space between the `mdframed` and the next paragraph. Inserting `\vskip0.5\baselineskip` or `vspace{0.5\baselineskip}` apparently not only inserts space but says it's a wonderful place for a page break.

It appears the `skipbelow` parameter of `mdframed` does a `\vskip`, so that leaves me in the same situation.

I know of the `needspace` package, but I can't predict how big the `mdframed` is going to be. If I need to I think I can store the `mdframed` height in the `aux` file and use that when laying out, but I'd rather not.

(When I try using `tcolorbox` in a similar manner it looks like `\nopagebreak` doesn't do anything at all -- either there is enough room for a line of text, or there is not, and that's all there is to it.)

It appears also that while this did work at the page break, it didn't seem to make a difference at the column break (preamble unchanged)

```
\title{Suppressing Page Breaks MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\vskip4\testskip
\lipsum[2]
\begin{test}
Testing 1 mdframed
\end{test}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

(For context, this is for a game reference book with many statblocks -- name and a set of statistics about the thing -- that I don't want to break up because reading stats across page boundaries is hard. Right now I'm adjusting them by hand, inserting or removing vertical space and breaks before or after the game entities as needed. I'd like to automate this more, and if I can get `mdframed` to allow space after it that doesn't cause a page break or column break that would do what I'm aiming for. Yes, it's a bit ugly, but it's eminently usable for my purpose.)

**Late-Night Ah-Ha!... that didn't work**

Obviously, wrapping the `mdframed` with a `minipage` should let me put some vertical space after the `mdframed` and then a `\nopagebreak` after!

```
\newenvironment{test}{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{mdframed}
}{
\end{mdframed}\bigskip\end{minipage}\nopagebreak
}
```

did not do as I had hoped. I think either the skip or the `minipage` still causes the `nopagebreak` to be ignored.

**2017-01-15 Update -- `\needspace` acting oddly**

The `needspace` solution suggested by @Schweinebacke almost worked, but I find cases where it doesn't. I cannot yet replicate them, but I can describe the symptoms.

- I have in front of me a page with a displayed `\pagetotal` of 461.9377pt and a `\pagegoal` of 682pt.
- The dimension passed to `\needspace` is 138.37pt. As far as I can tell, this should fit (461pt+138pt = about 600pt; about 80pt, over an inch, left over).
- Block got moved to the next page, and after the block is output I have a `\pagetotal` of 601.18pt (which is what it should have been on the *previous* page, had the block appeared there).

This does not happen consistently. Most often, `\needspace` works as expected: the block gets moved and the `\pagetotal` is reset to 0 before the block is output (i.e. I have in front of me one where the space needed was 136.55pt, `\pagetotal` after the block is 124.55pt (I wanted "height of block plus one line of text, `\bigskip` is about 12pt, so this all adds up more or less).

It looks as though `\needspace` determines the requested space is available, then the entire thing gets moved despite there evidently being enough space.

Am I doing something wrong with `\needspace` in my answer below?

**2017-01-18 Update: Why use `\needspace` at all?**

Browsing other questions, I stumbled on something I perhaps should have considered earlier... these blocks are being used much as fancy -- and big -- headings. This includes possibly being included in the Table of Contents.

Is there any reason I couldn't use `\@startsection`? Treat it like a section (positive space above and below) with a potentially big section heading, then call it done.

Simple answer... it doesn't work the way I need. I could use it to, say, draw a pretty frame around the section heading (useful to know), but the other elements that I need (title and body content in the frame) really aren't suited for section-style semantics. Which I would have realized had I thought about it for a moment.

Answer (score 5):

`mdframed` (and `tcolorbox`) have their own page break algorithms to allow breaks in the boxes. So it is a little bit complicated to put them into another box. But you can put the contents of a `mdframed` into a box and output this box inside the `mdframed`. You can measure the height and depth of this box and use the result (and some extra space) for `needspace`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newlength{\testskip}
\setlength{\testskip}{1\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{needspace}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{test}{%
  \par
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
}{
  \end{lrbox}
  \needspace{\dimexpr \ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+\testskip+2\fboxrule+\fboxsep+\baselineskip\relax}
  \begin{mdframed}\usebox\mybox\end{mdframed}
  \vskip\testskip
}

\title{Suppressing Page Breaks MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\begin{test}
Testing 1 mdframed
\end{test}
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, if you do not want a page break inside `mdframed`, there is no need to even use `mdframed`. You can simply put the text in a box and frame it yourself using whatever kind of frame you want:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\testskip}
\setlength{\testskip}{1\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{test}{%
  \par
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \minipage[b]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}
}{
    \endminipage
  \end{lrbox}
  \noindent\usebox\mybox\hskip\fboxsep\rule[-\dp\mybox]{\fboxrule}{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}\linebreak\nopagebreak
  \rule[\ht\strutbox]{\linewidth}{\fboxrule}
  \par\nobreak\vskip\testskip\nobreak
}

\title{Suppressing Page Breaks MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\begin{test}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{test}
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This very much sent me the direction I needed to go. I posted my own solution that goes a step further (creating an environment I can wrap around more or less arbitrary blocks... I think).

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Schweinebacke's answer, I have devised the following that appears to do all that I need. It works as I want across column breaks, page breaks, and in both twocolumn mode and when using `multicols`. It also works with `mdframed` if you surround the `mdframed` with a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}

\newlength{\NSCspace}
\newlength{\NSCspaceneeded} %debugging artifact, so I could output
\newsavebox\NSCbox
\newenvironment{needspacecalc}[1][0pt]{
\setlength{\NSCspace}{#1}
\begin{lrbox}{\NSCbox}
}{
\end{lrbox}
\setlength{\NSCspaceneeded}{\dimexpr\ht\NSCbox+\dp\NSCbox+\NSCspace\relax}
\needspace{\NSCspaceneeded}
\noindent\usebox\NSCbox
}

\title{Suppressing Page Breaks MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\begin{needspacecalc}[2\baselineskip] % "need two lines after this stuff
\begin{tcolorbox}
TColorBox stuff goes in here.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{needspacecalc}
\vskip\baselineskip
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment out the `\begin{needspacecalc}` and `\end{needspacecalc}` to see that this actually does force the column break.

Comment: ... *almost* works, something's not right. I've easily got space in this column (no MWE, this is a bigger document) and the object got moved to the next page.

Comment: You are adding a lot of presumably spurious spaces for somebody worried about spaces!

Comment: @cfr sorry? I'm a bit confused by this comment.

Comment: You need to comment (some of) your line endings. A new line is a space.

Comment: Ah. I was prepared to be quite annoyed if that was the problem, but it doesn't appear to be. I put ``%`` at the end of every line that could be relevant and find that I'm at 466.0pt/528.7pt and need 31.3pt and still got bumped to the next column.