# Adjust vertical space if pagebreak occurs in that place

Tags: plain-tex

I have an ornamental sign to separate sub-chapters defined like this:

```
\def\divider{
   \vskip2em plus.2em minus1em
   \hbox to\hsize{\hss ... \hss}
   \vskip2em plus.2em minus1em
}
```

I'd like the \vskip after the divider stretch (much) more if pagebreak occurs there - if it is at the bottom of the page, I prefer to have it ragged instead of stretching inter-paragraph spaces on that page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(In the end this turns out to be the same as @Gustavo Mezzetti's answer, but I didn't know it when I started as I hadn't read that answer yet. Anyway there's probably value in explaining things in multiple ways…)*

If I understand your question correctly, you want vertical glue that is infinite if there's a pagebreak after it (so that the page is ragged-bottom), and a specific finite value (`\vskip2em plus.2em minus1em`) otherwise. Recipes for doing things like this are scattered through the TeXbook, and in my opinion they are best learned from the Knuth–Plass paper [*Breaking Paragraphs into Lines*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13801528166755741890&hl=en&as_sdt=0,50).

Yours is a particularly simple case though: denoting glue by a triple of `(ideal, stretch, shrink)`, I'd use the following sequence:

- glue(0, ∞, 0)
- penalty
- glue(0, -∞, 0)
- glue(2em, .2em, 1em)

The idea is that

- if no page break occurs, then the infinite glues cancel each other out and the effect is exactly that of the finite glue you wanted, while
- if a page break is chosen (after the penalty), then all the following glue is discarded, so the effect is that of the infinite glue.

You can set the penalty to a negative or positive value, depending on how much you'd like to encourage or discourage a page break there. See more along these lines in the answer to [Understanding `needspace`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348994/understanding-needspace/364208#364208).

In particular, `plain.tex` defines `\filbreak` as `\def\filbreak{\par\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg}` (and this is retained in LaTeX) so you could just use `\filbreak` followed by your `\vskip2em plus.2em minus1em`, or you can change the penalty value.

Here's an example (put into say `divider.tex` and compile with `pdftex divider.tex`), first with your existing definition (the proposed changes commented out):

```
\hsize=5in \vsize=4in % Small page just to keep screenshot small
\parskip=0pt plus 100pt % Stretch exaggerated to be easier to see

\def\divider{
   \vskip2em plus.2em minus1em
   \hbox to\hsize{\hss \S \hss}
   % \vfil
   % \penalty 0
   % \vfilneg
   \vskip2em plus.2em minus1em
}

\input plipsum
\lipsum{1}

\divider

\lipsum{2-3}

\divider

\lipsum{5-6}

\bye
```

produces

[image: before]

(note the stretch between paragraphs) and after uncommenting the three lines, produces a ragged bottom instead of stretch:

[image: after]

You can read [Gustavo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372721/adjust-vertical-space-if-pagebreak-occurs-in-that-place#372839) for more refinements.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn’t the good ol’ `\filbreak` command do the trick, here?  Or am I missing something?  This command is described, along with an explanation of how it works, on page 111 of *The TeXbook*, third “dangerous bend”; it needs, perhaps, just to be adapted to your situation by changing the `\penalty` value.

The following is a complete, compilable example that I wrote in LaTeX simply for my convenience (`\usepackage{lipsum}` and so on), but the definition of the `\divider` macro uses only plain TeX constructs.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\divider}{
    \par % to begin with...
    \nobreak % I assume you don't want to allow a page break _before_ the 
             % divider
    \vskip 2ex plus.2ex minus1ex
    \hbox to\hsize{\hss $***$\hss}
    % Comment out the following lines, from "\nobreak" to "\vfilneg" 
    % (inclusive) and compare results:
    \nobreak
    \vfil
    \penalty 50 % adjust as you see it fits; but keep in mind that we are 
                % offering, in exchange, infinite stretchability for this page
    \vfilneg
    \vskip 2ex plus.2ex minus1ex
}

\flushbottom % we want to see if it works or not!



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\divider
\lipsum[2]\divider
\lipsum[3-4]\divider

\begingroup
    \centering
    \parbox[c][8\baselineskip]{.75\textwidth}{
        \centering
        \hrule
        \vfill
        Unbreakable box.
        \vfill
        \hrule
    }\par
\endgroup
\divider
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `\vskip2em plus.2em minus1em`. please use `\vspace*{2em plus.2em minus1em}`, please confirm if it will not meet the requirement

Comment: This does not address the question at all

Comment: I'd like to learn something and understand; if your answer is relevant (not sure) please add explanation what `\vspace*` does internally. I added the `plain-tex` tag (`\vspace` is a LaTeX macro) to see into the internals.